# jsx if else shorthand to hide element

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ecmascript-6, reactjs

I can do

```
<p>Company: {{this.state.user.company}}</p>
```

but sometime company has no value. So how should I hide the entire

if the property of company is null?

I tried

```
<p>({this.state.user.company} ? 'Company: ' + {this.state.user.company} : '')</p>
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alternative syntax to Ori Drori's answer (I find this a bit easier to read):

```
render() {
  return (
    {this.state.user.company ? <p>Company: {this.state.user.company}</p> : null}
  )
}
```

Answer (score 9):

React doesn't render falsy values, so you can use [short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation). If `this.state.user.company` is `null`, it will be ignored by react. If it's truthy, react will render the element after `&&`.

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
        {this.state.user.company &&
            <p>Company: {this.state.user.company}</p>
        }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Known as short circuiting.

Comment: what if I have 10 item? I have to write this.state.something, can I assign a variable to holder the object before return function ?

Comment: Thanks @Chad - added.

Comment: @JessieEmerson - if you've got an array of items, you can filter them, and render just what you need, or map them and return null, and the null items will be ignored by react. I prefer the filtering method.

Comment: is it built in react? there are some param like org_url I don't want to shows.

Comment: @JessieEmerson - short circuit, array#filter and array#map are standard language feature. React ignore falsy values is built into react.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:

```
render() {
  if (!this.state.user.company) return (<p>Loading...</p>)

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Name: {this.state.user.company.name}</p>
      <p>Address: {this.state.user.company.address}</p>
      <p>Creation date: {this.state.user.company.creation}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: This only works if the `<p>` element is the only thing the component is rendering

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the following for a short handed format:

```
render() {
  return (
    {this.state.user.company ?? <p>Company: {this.state.user.company}</p>}
  )
}
```

[Reference Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)